# react-ultimate-pagination component setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I'm trying to use this package react-ultimate-pagination: https://github.com/ultimate-pagination/react-ultimate-pagination

I want to set it up like their basic demo example: https://codepen.io/dmytroyarmak/pen/GZwKZJ

The usage instructions at the bottom of the github page say to import the component like this:

```
import ReactUltimatePagination from 'react-ultimate-pagination';
```

But the codepen demo just shows a constant:

```
const UltimatePagination = reactUltimatePaginationBasic.default;
```

I copied the code from the demo, but since it is mismatched with the import, I have an error of UltimatePagination being undefined and reactUltimatePaginationBasic undefined.

Does anyone know how to set up this component like the demo example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `var ReactUltimatePagination = require('react-ultimate-pagination');` after you've installed it with `npm install react-ultimate-pagination --save`

Answer (score 5):

The module exports the higher oder component `createUltimatePagination` as a named export. To import it using es6 import syntax it has to be the following:

```
import {createUltimatePagination} from 'react-ultimate-pagination';
```

**Example App**:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import { createUltimatePagination } from "react-ultimate-pagination";

const Button = ({ value, isActive, disabled, onClick }) => (
  <button
    style={isActive ? { fontWeight: "bold" } : null}
    onClick={onClick}
    disabled={disabled}
  >
    {value}
  </button>
);

const PaginatedPage = createUltimatePagination({
  itemTypeToComponent: {
    PAGE: Button,
    ELLIPSIS: () => <Button value="..." />,
    FIRST_PAGE_LINK: () => <Button value="First" />,
    PREVIOUS_PAGE_LINK: () => <Button value="Prev" />,
    NEXT_PAGE_LINK: () => <Button value="Next" />,
    LAST_PAGE_LINK: () => <Button value="Last" />
  }
});

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    page: 1
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <PaginatedPage
        totalPages={10}
        currentPage={this.state.page}
        onChange={page => this.setState({ page })}
      />
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Also see this working example on codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/01n2y3r4nl)

To be honest I played around with the api of that library and actually it is unclear to me how this library is intended to be used. A pagination component should receive a list of items and then provide a [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) to render the current page with a slice of these items. It's a pagination that does not paginate. Basically it's only a button bar.

Comment: how do i include the theme with this syntax? example how do i specify I need bootstrap3